# keycloak doesn't work with asp.net MVC5 web app (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, keycloak

I am trying to connect my MVC5 web application with Keycloak server v1.98. It is connected. When I access my web app, Keycloak require entering the credentials, and when I enter it I get the exception below:

My Configuration (startup.cs):

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        const string persistentAuthType = "WebApplication1_cookie_auth";

        // --- Cookie Authentication Middleware - Persists user sessions between requests
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = persistentAuthType
        });
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(persistentAuthType); // Cookie is primary session store

        // --- Keycloak Authentication Middleware - Connects to central Keycloak database
        app.UseKeycloakAuthentication(new KeycloakAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // App-Specific Settings
            ClientId = "dotnettest", // *Required*

            VirtualDirectory = "", // Set this if you use a virtual directory when deploying to IIS

            // Instance-Specific Settings
            Realm = "dotnettest", // Don't change this unless told to do so
            KeycloakUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:9090/auth", // Enter your Keycloak URL here

            // Template-Specific Settings
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = persistentAuthType, // Sets the above cookie with the Keycloak data
            AuthenticationType = "WebApplication1_keycloak_auth", // Unique identifier for the auth middleware
            ClientSecret = "187a2ba7-91f9-479f-a290-2b249a64236a"
        });
    }
```

Exception Details:

```
System.Exception: Both the access token and the refresh token have expired
```

Stack Trace:

```
[Exception: Both the access token and the refresh token have expired]
   KeycloakIdentityModel.<GetClaimsAsync>d__39.MoveNext() +708
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   KeycloakIdentityModel.<ToClaimsIdentityAsync>d__25.MoveNext() +156
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) +11522180
   Owin.Security.Keycloak.Middleware.<InvokeAsync>d__1.MoveNext() +1066
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +445
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +187
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +653
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +187
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext() +185
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +69
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +64
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +380
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I followed this tutorial:

https://github.com/dylanplecki/KeycloakOwinAuthentication/wiki/ASP.NET-MVC-Tutorial

Thanks.

Comment: Would you let me know do you register it in MVC 5 as an external provider? I followed guide line but there is not success, the button didn't appear.

Comment: @Madnik7G try to create new project (asp.net mvc 5) and follow the tutorial then its will work fine, you don;t need ti register anything you will use asp.net membership provider just by editing Configuration method in startup.cs file,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolved by editing machine time zone into (utc -1:00), this issue appears because there is bug in KeycloakOwinAuthentication project and the bug has been reported to project developer.

you can solve the problem by editing the method "GetClaimsAsync" in "KeycloakIdentity.cs" file to compare current datetime in (UTC-1) zone.

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> GetClaimsAsync()
        {
            await _refreshLock.WaitAsync();
            try
            {
                // Check to update cached claims, but not if refresh token is missing (as in bearer mode)
                if ((_kcClaims == null || _accessToken.ValidTo <= DateTime.Now) && _refreshToken != null)
                {
                    var info = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Tokyo Standard Time");
                    DateTimeOffset localServerTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
                    DateTimeOffset utc = localServerTime.ToUniversalTime();
                    // Validate refresh token expiration
                    if (_refreshToken.ValidTo <= utc.AddHours(-1))
                        throw new Exception("Both the access token and the refresh token have expired");
                    // Load new identity from token endpoint via refresh token
                    await RefreshIdentity(_refreshToken.RawData);
                }
                return GetCurrentClaims();
            }
            finally
            {
                _refreshLock.Release();
            }
        }
```

Comment: After that you need to rebuild both projects, and manually add KeycloakIdentityModel and Owin.Security.Keycloak dlls to your projectand use them instead of the original ones you set earlier through the NuGet package

Comment: For other late arrivals: KeycloakOwinAuthentication was [discontinued](https://github.com/dylanplecki/KeycloakOwinAuthentication/issues/54).
Use  Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect with the realm in the Authority-URI.